# Creating duplicates using Union with a filter

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to duplicate my data but change one value in one column. For example I need my data to look like this per every (to) and (from)..

```
  to    from    vehicle size    l   h
 FCS011 FCS416  6025         0.1       0.3
 FCS011 FCS416  6020         0.1    0.3
 FCS011 FCS416  6010         0.1    0.3
 FCS011 FCS416  6015         0.1    0.3
```

Now for some (to) and (from) sets I only have data where vehicle size is 6010 and 6015 and for some I have only data for 6025 and 6020. I need to duplicated the values for the given set that is missing data for one or the other set.

My data currently looks like this for some of the sets (market_to,market_from)

```
 to     from    vehicle size    l     h
 FCS010 FCS416  6025         0.1       0.3
 FCS010 FCS416  6020         0.1       0.3
 FCS012 FCS416  6010         0.1       0.3
 FCS012 FCS416  6015         0.1       0.3
```

This data set should look like this:

```
      to      from  vehicle size    l       h
      FCS010    FCS416  6025         0.1       0.3
      FCS010    FCS416  6020         0.1       0.3
      FCS010    FCS416  6010         0.1       0.3
      FCS010    FCS416  6015         0.1       0.3
      FCS012    FCS416  6010         0.1       0.3
      FCS012    FCS416  6015         0.1       0.3
      FCS012    FCS416  6020         0.1       0.3
      FCS012    FCS416  6025         0.1       0.3
```

So I wanted to do a union all, to capture other values but I am not sure how to capture the logic of either its one or the other. Below is my query that I did a union to create extra rows..

```
 create table PA_FCS_temp
 as
 select 
 MARKET_FROM ,
 MARKET_TO ,
 VEHICLE_CLASS,
 l,
 h
 from PA_FCS
 UNION ALL
 select MARKET_FROM ,
 MARKET_TO ,
 decode(VEHICLE_CLASS, '6020', '6025', '6010', '6015') as VEHICLE_CLASS,        
 l,
 h

 from PA_FCS
 VEHICLE_CLASS in ('6020', '6010')

 ORDER BY MARKET_FROM, MARKET_TO;
```

Comment: Let's take the two rows with `"to" = FCS012, "from" = FCS416`. Each row has a value for `l` and a value for `h`. In all your examples, all the `l` are the same, and all the `h` are the same. What is the desired output, though, if `l` (for example) was **different** between the two rows? Which value do you need to "duplicate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiplex records only ending with `5` ( `6015`, `6025` ) by using modular logic with *cross join* as

```
select * from t where mod(vehicle_size,10)=0
union all
select t1.* 
  from t t1 cross join t t2 
 where mod(t1.vehicle_size,5)=0
   and mod(t1.vehicle_size,10)!=0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/BDCF14868)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

One way to think of your problem isn't as "duplicating rows" but rather as "filling in sparse data".

You have a list of known vehicle sizes: 6010, 6015, 6020, and 6025.  You have sets of data given by `market_to` and `market_from`, where each set may not contain all of the known vehicle sizes.  You want to fill in the sparse data so that each set contains every known vehicle size.

A good SQL tool in Oracle for filling in sparse data is the "partitioned" outer join.  Here is how that would work for your query:

#### Setup

```
CREATE TABLE market_data (  
  market_to varchar2(6), 
  market_from varchar2(6), 
  vehicle_size number(4),
  l number,
  h number);

INSERT INTO market_data
 SELECT 'FCS010','FCS416',6025,  0.1, 0.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'FCS010','FCS416',6020,  0.1, 0.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'FCS012','FCS416',6010,  0.1, 0.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'FCS012','FCS416',6015,  0.1, 0.3 FROM DUAL ;

 COMMIT;
```

#### Partitioned Outer Join Query

(note: if you have a table with known vehicle sizes, you can use that and omit the `WITH` clause.)

```
with vehicle_sizes ( vehicle_size ) AS 
  ( SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(sys.odcinumberlist(6010, 6015, 6020, 6025)) )
select md.market_from, 
       md.market_to,
       vs.vehicle_size,
       nvl(md.l, min(md.l) over ( partition by md.market_from, md.market_to )) l,
       nvl(md.h, min(md.h) over ( partition by md.market_from, md.market_to )) h
from market_data md partition by (md.market_to, md.market_from) 
right outer join vehicle_sizes vs on vs.vehicle_size = md.vehicle_size;
```

> ```
> +-------------+-----------+--------------+-----+-----+
> | MARKET_FROM | MARKET_TO | VEHICLE_SIZE |  L  |  H  |
> +-------------+-----------+--------------+-----+-----+
> | FCS416      | FCS010    |         6010 | 0.1 | 0.3 |
> | FCS416      | FCS010    |         6015 | 0.1 | 0.3 |
> | FCS416      | FCS010    |         6020 | 0.1 | 0.3 |
> | FCS416      | FCS010    |         6025 | 0.1 | 0.3 |
> | FCS416      | FCS012    |         6010 | 0.1 | 0.3 |
> | FCS416      | FCS012    |         6015 | 0.1 | 0.3 |
> | FCS416      | FCS012    |         6020 | 0.1 | 0.3 |
> | FCS416      | FCS012    |         6025 | 0.1 | 0.3 |
> +-------------+-----------+--------------+-----+-----+
> ```